# How to checkout the source code of keras 2.15.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pypi

The latest version of `keras` in `pypi` is `2.15.0`:

https://pypi.org/project/keras/

```
keras 2.15.0
pip install keras

Latest version
Released: Nov 7, 2023
```

But the latest release of `keras` in `github` is `2.14.0`:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases

```
Keras Release 2.14.0 Latest
What's Changed

    [keras/layers/normalization] Standardise docstring usage of "Default to" by @SamuelMarks in #17965
    Update Python ver to 3.9 in Dockerfile by @sampathweb in #18076
    [keras/saving/legacy/saved_model] Standardise docstring usage of "Default to" by @SamuelMarks in #17978
    [keras/metrics] Standardise docstring usage of "Default to" by @SamuelMarks in #17972
    Update example losses to bce- metrics/confusion_metrics.py by @Frightera in #18045
...
```

Where to download the source code for `keras` version `2.15.0`?

Comment: You can download it from [here](https://pypi.org/project/keras/2.15.0/#files)?

Comment: The file in it is not the source code.

Comment: "The file"... what file are you talking about? There is no mention to a specific file in your question.

Comment: There is no any "`WORKSPACE`" file in the `pypi` source file "`keras-2.15.0.tar.gz`" in https://pypi.org/project/keras/2.15.0/#files, but the "`WORKSPACE`" file existed in the github version "`v2.14.0.tar.gz`" in https://github.com/keras-team/keras/archive/refs/tags/v2.14.0.tar.gz, So the file "`keras-2.15.0.tar.gz`" is not the real source code.

Comment: You are wrong, there are more files in github because they can be CI or other stuff that is specific to github, so this is not a test for being the "real" source code. You can download the source from pypi and just install it to check (python setup.py install).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ve opened an issue for creating v2.15.0 tag (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/18931) and now it is done by keras-team contributor: **https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/v2.15.0**

You can now git checkout v2.15.0